# My app doesn't automatically scroll up after adding ScrollToTop Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, react-router, components

First time using React this week and I'm trying to create a fetch Github app, everything is working but the scroll to the top. When I scroll down and click on the view Repo I want the screen to automatically scroll up, I've copied the code via the React Docs and I am using React-Router-Dom version 5 however nothing is scrolling up. Please see below for my code, where am I going wrong guys?

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export default function ScrollToTop() {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [pathname]);

  return null;
}
```

App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import RepoPage from './components/RepoPage';
import ScrollToTop from './components/ScrollToTop';


function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
    <div className="App">
    <h1>Want to see other people's projects? Enter a Github username and Voila!</h1>
    <ScrollToTop />
    <Switch>
      <Route>
      <RepoPage />
      </Route>
     </Switch>
    </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Snippet of my Repo.js component

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import RepoDetails from './RepoDetails';
import ScrollToTop from './ScrollToTop';
import '../App.css'

    function renderRows(repo) {
        return(
            <div 
                className='repo-button' 
                onClick={() => getDetails(repo.name)}
                key={repo.id}
            >
                <h3 className='repo-name'>
                {repo.name}
                <button onCLick={<ScrollToTop />}>View Repo</button>
                </h3>
            </div>

        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be some misunderstanding with how `ScrollToTop` function component is used.  I think when used in the `App` component, it is meant to automatically scroll to the top when the `pathname` changes.  We can probably add this similar behavior for when the `View Repo` button is clicked by passing a callback function to `onClick` like `() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)` instead of the function component.

Answer (score 0):

Not to worry I've fixed the issue, I've set the window scroll to the top within the button onClick tag. Thanks anyway